# How to copy fields for one table to another table on Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a single database called as **`college`** and two tables called as **`student`** and **`student Personal details`**, Student table contains `stud.Name, dept, address1,address2,address3`. Now I feel like `address1, address2 and address3` field values move to **`student Personal details`**(contain same fields) table. What is the SQL query to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE `college`.`student`, `college`.`student personal details`
SET 
`college`.`student`.`address1` = `college`.`student personal details`.`address1`,
`college`.`student`.`address2` = `college`.`student personal details`.`address2`,
`college`.`student`.`address3` = `college`.`student personal details`.`address3`
WHERE
`college`.`student`.`id` = `college`.`student personal details`.`id`;

I assume that `id`'s are the primary keys you have set for the tables.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Reddy

Comment: Just now i try this Query working fine thanks @Abhishek Readdy

Answer (score 1):

use insert - select, query as below, correct it as per your actual fields

```
insert into studentPersonaldetails (address1, address2, address3) 
select address1, address2, address3 from student 
where student.name = studentPersonaldetails.name
```

Comment: Thanks @KP its working fine

Comment: @udayakumarb, Kindly accept the answer, which is the tick below the vote